# Run ipconfig command with php

Tags: php, windows, cmd, mac-address, ipconfig

I use this code to understand some information of visitors (clients). It has been running on my virtual server on Xampp, but I can`t run on my main server (host). I see just a blank page.

```
$info = system('ipconfig /all');
echo $info;
```

Comment: Is the main server a windows based server?

Comment: No, the server has Linux os (Apache).

Comment: ipconfig doesn't run on linux. use ifconfig for that

Comment: `ipconfig` returns the network information of the server, not of the client that connects.

Answer (score 3):

this might help you

**Server IP**

You can get the server IP address from `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`.

**Client IP address**

You can get the client IP from `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

**Edit**: you ask in comments how to get the output of an external command - one way is to use backticks, e.g.

```
$ipAddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$macAddr=false;

#run the external command, break output into lines
$arp=`arp -a $ipAddress`;
$lines=explode("\n", $arp);

#look for the output line describing our IP address
foreach($lines as $line)
{
   $cols=preg_split('/\s+/', trim($line));
   if ($cols[0]==$ipAddress)
   {
       $macAddr=$cols[1];
   }
}
```

**But what if the client isn't on a LAN?**

Well, you're out of luck unless you can have the client volunteer that information and transmit via other means. See Peter G Mac's suggestion for using Javascript.

you can also try following command

```
 <?php
  // http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#85930

  $_ = null;

  // If you care about the return value, use this:
    passthru("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /c custom.bat",$_);
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    echo $_;
  // if you don't care, just use this:
    $_ = exec("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /c custom.bat");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This would only get the ***servers*** IP information not the client. Because you are running the code on your local PC you will see your local information (which will be the same as the server information).

Also if your hosts server is running linux, the command would be `ifconfig`, but that would still only get the server information.

Comment: This server is apache. So, why it`s running on xampp?

Comment: xampp runs apache as a server. xampp is just a wrapper around a lamp instalation (php, mysql , apache)

Comment: `ipconfig`/`ifconfig` an OS dependant command not an `Apache`/`PHP` one

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you clarified that the server is linux based, the correct command on linux is

```
/sbin/ifconfig -a
```

The data returned will look slightly different

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 0000::000:0000:0000:0000/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:14141910 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6532919 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4462743134 (4.4 GB)  TX bytes:1340503018 (1.3 GB)
          Interrupt:22 Memory:f6ae0000-f6b00000
```